# Function minimization with multiple variables and constraints

Tags: analysis, optimization

The definition of my problem is the following: Assume that you have a function 
$F(\omega)$ which is continuous and has in general all analytical properties. I want to find a set of parameters, $(\alpha_i, V_i)$ with $i \in {0,1,2,3,...}$ such that: $F(\omega) = \omega - \sum\limits_{i}\frac{V_i*V_i^\ast}{\omega - a_i}$.

Is there anyone that can give a well-defined methodology for such a problem?? I was trying to use the conjugate gradient method, but the problem is that 
I need a specific set of the parameters, same for all $\omega$ points...

Thanks!

Comment: "has in general all analytical properties" -- do you mean you don't care whether it is differentiable or continuous or something like that, as long as it works? Also, what is the domain of this function? $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Exactly, I don't care about being continuous differentiable or so as long as it works. Also it's defined in complex plane.